# Entity Framework Update Not Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

using .net 4.5.2, MVC5, Entity framework 6 and visual studio 2015.

I have a repository pattern set up with Ninject as my DI here is the **common** file.

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserBlueRayLists>().To<UserBlueRayListRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IBlueRays>().To<BlueRaysRepository>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

my **Context**

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public IDbSet<UserBlueRayList> UserBlueRayLists { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<BlueRays> BlueRays { get; set; }

    public new void SaveChanges()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IDevTestContext
{
    IDbSet<UserBlueRayList> UserBlueRayLists { get; set; }
    IDbSet<BlueRays> BlueRays { get; set; }

    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Then my **Repository update** method.

```
public bool Update(UserBlueRayList item)
    {
        var userBRList = _db.UserBlueRayLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
        if(userBRList != null)
        {

            userBRList = item;
            //_db.Entry(userBRList).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now when i save via my controller and call the repository update method, nothing is updated.

So i use

> _db.Entry(userBRList).State = EntityState.Modified;

But i get an error,

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'myapp.Models.UserBlueRayList' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values... etc

Many to many models, userlist model.

```
public class UserBlueRayList
{
    public UserBlueRayList()
    {
        this.BlueRays = new HashSet<BlueRays>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlueRays> BlueRays { get; set; }
}
```

And the

```
public class BlueRays
{
    public BlueRays()
    {
        this.UserBlueRayList = new HashSet<UserBlueRayList>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<UserBlueRayList> UserBlueRayList { get; set; }
}
```

Question is why this wont update, and why it errors if i try to set state to modified.

Comment: The line `userBRList = item` just replaces the entity, but it isn't being tracked by your context.

Comment: So instead i need to populate it manually like userBrList.name = item.Name?

Comment: That is one way to do it. You can also do it by not getting the entity from the database first and then attaching `item`

Comment: What do you mean? could you show me the correct way?

Comment: In your update method, `item` (I think) has no primary key or whichever index you're using as primary key. Simply replacing an existing record with it won't work, and hence the `EntityState.Modified` line gives an error. One workaround is to manually assign all the properties onto the existing record then save changes.

Comment: @lemunk try to modify as, context.TableName.Attach(entityDetails);
                    context.Entry(entityDetails).State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using EF6, you may try to use auto property mapping built into EF6

```
public bool Update(UserBlueRayList item)
    {
        var userBRList = _db.UserBlueRayLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
        if(userBRList != null)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(userBRList).CurrentValues.SetValues(item); 
            return return _dbContext.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

First Solution you have to update like that

```
public bool Update(UserBlueRayList item)
{
    var userBRList = _db.UserBlueRayLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
    if(userBRList != null)
    {

        userBRList.Name = item.Name;
         //value assign to other entity
        _db.Entry(userBRList).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

if this will not solve your problem you Find method instead of FirstorDefault()

```
public bool Update(UserBlueRayList item)
{
var userBRList = _db.UserBlueRayLists.Find(x => x.Id == item.Id);
if(userBRList != null)
{

    userBRList.Name = item.Name;
     //value assign to other entity
    _db.Entry(userBRList).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```